# Confusion around spin_lock_irqsave: in what nested situation is interrupt state kept?

Tags: linux-kernel, spinlock, smp, preemption

There are many Q&As about spinlocks, but it's still confusing to me. I think it's because the questions and answers assume different settings or not clearly explain the settings about if it's SMP or if it's preemptive kernel or not when they ask or answer (and some old info is mixed in too).

My first question is: (**Q1**) in SMP situation, is `schedule()` run on every processor concurrently (I know the scheduling starts by jiffies timer interrupt)? I'll assume yes in my question below. I would appreciate it if someone could briefly explain it to me how processes move among processor cores during scheduling too.

I'm trying to understand how, why, when `spin_lock/unlock_irqsave` is used. Here is my question.

Suppose there is a code which calls `spin_lock_irqsave`, and the interrupt state (enable) was a 'disable' at the time of calling `spin_lock_irqsave()`. Could this code be running in interrupt context? Probably not, because the ISR should not have kicked in in the first place if interrupt was disabled in the corresponding local processor. Therefore, the code calling `spin_lock_irqsave` must be in process context. Ok, the interrupt had been disabled previously, but a process is trying to lock with `spin_lock_irqsave`.

In what case could the interrupt have been disabled? I think there are two cases.

Case 1: a previous interrupt routine had been preempted by this process (which is calling this `spin_lock_irqsave`). This is weird because ISR cannot be preempted. (**Q2**) By the way, in preemptive kernel, can ISR be preempted by a process? (**Q3**) I guess because the `preempt_count()` is `#define`d as `(current_thread_info()->preempt_count)`, the `preempt_disable` only works for process and not interrupt. Do interrupts also have the current thread info?

Case 2: a previous normal process had acquired the lock with `spin_lock_irq` (or `irqsave`). But this also is weird because before locking, `spin_lock_irq` (or `irqsave`) disables preemption and interrupt for the task telling the scheduler not to switch to other task after the scheduler timer interrupt. So this case cannot be true.

I know I have to look further about process scheduling for SMP and kernel preemption, and maybe I am misunderstanding something. Could somebody clear things up in my question? Thanks a lot for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There are many Q&As about spinlocks, but it's still confusing to me. I think it's because the questions and answers assume different settings or not clearly explain the settings about if it's SMP or if it's preemptive kernel or not when they ask or answer (and some old info is mixed in too).

I can only agree. Spinlocks, while simple in nature, are not a simple topic at all when included in the context of modern Linux kernels. I don't think you can get a good understanding of spinlocks just by reading random and case-specific Stack Overflow answers.

I would strongly suggest you to read [*Chapter 5: Concurrency and Race Conditions*](https://static.lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch05.pdf) of the book [*Linux Device Drivers*](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/), which is freely available online. In particular, the "Spinlocks" section of Chapter 5 is very helpful to understand how spinlocks are useful in different situations.

> (**Q1**) in SMP situation, is `schedule()` run on every processor concurrently? [...] I would appreciate it if someone could briefly explain it to me how processes move processor cores during scheduling too.

Yes, you can look at it that way if you like. Each CPU (i.e. every single processor core) has its own timer, and when a timer interrupt is raised on a given CPU, that CPU executes the timer interrupt handler registered by the kernel, which calls the scheduler, which re-schedules processes.

Each CPU in the system has its own *runqueue*, which holds tasks that are in a runnable state. Any task can be included in at most one runqueue and cannot run on multiple different CPUs at the same time.

The CPU affinity of a task is what determines which CPUs a task can be run on. The default "normal" affinity allows a task to run on any CPU (except in special configurations). Based on their affinity, tasks can be moved from one runqueue to another either by the scheduler or if they require so through the `sched_setaffinity` syscall (here's [a related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49709782/3889449) which explains how).

Suggested read: [*A complete guide to Linux process scheduling*](https://trepo.tuni.fi/bitstream/handle/10024/96864/GRADU-1428493916.pdf).

> Suppose there is a code which calls `spin_lock_irqsave`, and the interrupt state (enable) was a 'disable' at the time of calling `spin_lock_irqsave()`. Could this code be running in interrupt context? Probably not.

Why not? This is possible. The code could be running in interrupt context, but not called by a *different* interrupt. See the bottom of my answer.

> Case 1: a previous interrupt routine had been preempted by this process (which is calling this `spin_lock_irqsave`). This is weird because ISR cannot be preempted.

You're right, it's weird. More than weird though, this is *impossible*. On Linux, at all times, interrupts can either be enabled or disabled (there is no in-between). There isn't really a "priority" for interrupts (like there is for tasks), but we can classify them in two ranks:

- Non-preemptible interrupts which necessarily need to run from start to finish with full control of the CPU. These interrupts put the system in the "disabled interrupts" state and no other interrupts can happen.
- Preemptible interrupts which are re-entrant and allow other interrupts to happen. In case another interrupt happens when this interrupt is being serviced, you enter in a nested interrupt scenario, which is similar to the scenario of nested signal handlers for tasks.

In your case, since interrupts had previously been disabled, this means that if the code that disabled them was an interrupt, it was a non-preemptible one, and therefore it could not have been preempted. It could also have been a preemptible interrupt which is executing a critical portion of code that needs interrupts to be disabled, but the scenario is still the same, you cannot be inside *another* interrupt.

> (**Q2**) By the way, in preemptive kernel, can ISR be preempted by a process?

No. It's improper to say "preempted by a process". Processes do not really preempt anything, they *are preempted* by the kernel which takes control. That said, a preemptible interrupt *could* in theory be interrupted by another one that was for example registered by a process (I don't know an example case for this scenario unfortunately). I still wouldn't call this "preempted by a process" though, since the whole thing keeps happening in kernel space.

> (**Q3**) [...] Do interrupts also have the current thread info?

Interrupt handlers live in a different world, they do not care about running tasks and do not need access to such information. You probably could get ahold of `current` or even `current_thread_info` *if you really wanted*, but I doubt that'd be of any help for anything. An interrupt is not associated with any task, there's no link between the interrupt and a certain task running. Another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10648616/3889449) for reference.

> Case 2: a previous normal process had acquired the lock with `spin_lock_irq` (or `irqsave`). But this also is weird because before locking, `spin_lock_irq` (or `irqsave`) disables preemption and interrupt for the task telling the scheduler not to switch to other task after the scheduler timer interrupt. So this case cannot be true.

Yes, you're right. That's not possible.

---

The `spin_lock_irqsave()` function exists to be used in circumstances in which you cannot know if interrupts have already been disabled or not, and therefore you cannot use `spin_lock_irq()` followed by `spin_unlock_irq()` because that second function would *forcibly re-enable* interrupts. By the way, this is also explained in Chapter 5 of Linux Device Drivers, which I linked above.

In the scenario you describe, you are calling `spin_lock_irqsave()` and interrupts have already been disabled by something else. This means that any of the parent caller functions that ended up calling the current function must have already disabled interrupts somehow.

The following scenarios are possible:

1. The original interrupt disable was caused by an interrupt handler and you are now executing another piece of code *as part of the same interrupt handler* (i.e. the current function has been called either directly or indirectly by the interrupt handler itself). You can very well have a call to `spin_lock_irqsave()` in a function that is being called by an interrupt handler. Or even just a call to `local_irqsave()` (the `kfree()` function does this for example, and it can surely be called from interrupt context).
2. The original interrupt disable was caused by normal kernel code and you are now executing another piece of code *as part of the same normal kernel code* (i.e. the current function has been called either directly or indirectly by some other kernel function after disabling interrupts). This is completely possible, and in fact it's the reason why the `irqsave` variant exists.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That clarified several things to me. I've read the 'Linux device driver, by Corbet' but some things were not kindly explained, like when it is not clear if interrupt is disabled.. now I understand it much better.  Just one question, in some architectures, I think higher priority interrupt routine can start preempting a lower priority interrupt service routine, isn't it correct? maybe this can be another case we are not sure interrupt is enabled or not seen from the higher priority ISR code. and I saw in sparc architecture, the spin_lock_irqsave stores the 4 bit interrupt level.

Comment: And though a process is run only in one processor at the same time, moving from core to core..as  you said, I realize there can be several processes running same code, or even many instances of a same program(like when we run many independent same browsers), that  could be another case where the code doesn't know if the interrupt is disabled or not.

Comment: @ChanKim *"I think higher priority interrupt routine can start preemptinh a lower priority interrupt service routine"* - Yes, my bad there, since you were saying that interrupts are disabled I was assuming only the high priority interrupts. I have updated my answer under "Case 1" above to make it clarere.

Comment: I read your updated answer again(because I was confused again reading a book :) ). You said "Processes do not really preempt anything, they are preempted by the kernel which takes control.", but I understand 'preemption' doesn't mean the scheduler(by the timer interrupt)'s intervention itself during a normal user process or kernel process, but switching to another process by the result of the scheduling. I think this is an important point for many people. What do you think about my understanding?

Comment: @ChanKim Preemption does not mean "switching to another process". Preemption means to forcibly take control of the CPU in order to run the scheduler. Switching to another process might happen or it might not (for example the scheduler could decide to keep the current task running). Switching to another process might also happen naturally, *without* preemption: for example if a process terminates execution through the exit syscall the next task to run is automatically chosen without the need to preempt the current task.

Comment: @ChanKim As far as I know, a low priority interrupt handler *cannot* be preempted by the scheduler, it can only be interrupted by another interrupt handler. And that's what I was trying to say in the answer to your Q2.

Comment: Boneli I see, I remember reading that when a kernel is 'non-preemptable', any kernel code is not interrupted by the scheduler until it relinquishes the CPU. (like before kernel 2.4?) Thanks, it helped a lot.

Comment: @Boneli ah.. I'm reading this again.  you said "Why not? This is possible. The code could be running in interrupt context, but not called by a different interrupt." Shouldn't it be "... but now called by a different interrupt"? Was it a typo?

Comment: @ChanKim Not a typo. See the bottom of my answer, point 1. If you are in a scenario in which interrupts are disabled and you find yourself calling `spin_lock_irqsave()` then the code that did this must be coming from the same interrupt that disabled the interrupts in the first place.